# Unable to retrieve SharePoint CU's from Windows Update

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

I had planned to update one of our farms last weekend but no CU's were retrieved with Windows Update? I have not had this issue last time I patched a farm. Anyone else had this issue recently?

The farm patch level at the moment is February 16 - 15.0.4797.1000. The only SharePoint patch that was picked up by windows update was this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3115014

I know I can manually install the updates but, windows update seems to be a cleaner way of doing it. Plus, this is a very large farm and would take a few days to restore if there was a issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I never used windows update for installing SP related patches. The rule is to manually install each of the update in QA and test it before moving to Prod.

Comment: Hi, ye I've done this in test. Test managed to pick up the CU's. I had to force the June patch manually and disable the farm version detection  PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1 I really don't want to do this in Live. Too much of a risk!

Answer (score 0):

CUs are not typically available via Windows Update - see [http://www.toddklindt.com](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=556) for details.

PUs (public updates; security updates rather than fixes) however DO arrive via Windows Update. Note that some of them require the SharePoint configuration wizard to be run on all servers in the farm following installation, which will not be done automatically by Windows Update.

Therefore, to install CUs for SharePoint, you'll need to manually download them and apply them to your farm servers, then run the wizard on all farm servers. [www.toddklindt.com](http://www.toddklindt.com/default.aspx) is a good place to keep an eye on the patches that have been amde available, as well as any bugs, notes or regressions that the patches may cause on your farm. Read these notes before installing a CU, and if the patch fixes something you need fixing, but breaks something else that may impact you, you have to make a judgement call on whether to install the patch or not.

So, in short, CUs should be downloaded and installed manually and remember to run the wizard on all farm servers.

Answer (score 0):

Only security Updates available via the windows update, as this decision made on Feb 2015.
[SharePoint CUs and Windows Update – Important Update!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/02/26/sharepoint-cus-and-windows-update-important-update/)

All non-Security( I.e CU) updates you have to manually download from the Microsoft Download center.

SharePoint CU required special Handling, Installation of Patch followed by the SharePoint Config wizard.